# how to format output of expanded variable

Tags: variables, powershell, format, output

I am trying to make a variable equal the output of query but so i can pipe to another command but its not working as i hoped. here is what i have.

$office=get-aduser "samaccountname" -properties * | select office

I already tried using sub-expressions $folder= get-aduser "samaccountname" -properties * | select '$(office)' and
@{n='office';e={$_.office -replace '^office='$1'}} neither of which remove the @{office=}
My goal is to get $office=office but instead i get $office=@{office=}

How do you remove the @{} from the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
$office = (Get-ADUser "samAccountName" -properties office).Office
```

**EDIT**

Another way (which may or may not be easier to understand) is:

```
$user = Get-ADUser "samAccountName" -properties office
$office = $user.office
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help.. Here we are executing the expression in the Parentheses first and then returning the value of the Office property. Revised Answer.