# How does data differ in a csv

Tags: powershell, output

I am trying to pull from 2 columns using the script below but keep receiving an error:

Set-DistributionGroup : The operation couldn't be performed because object '@{d
lgroup=group1; manager=user1}.dlgroup' couldn't be found on "server"

csv file is standard group,user
                     group2,user2

```
import-csv "dls.csv" | foreach {
   set-distributiongroup -identity "$_.dlgroup" -managedby "$_.manager"
}
```

what is @{ and why is the output showing as @{d
lgroup=group1; manager=user1}.dlgroup? i have tried using double quotes with the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use SubExpressions (haven't got a chance to test now), So:

```
Import-CSV "dls.csv" | ForFach {
    Set-Distributiongroup -identity "$($_.dlgroup)" -managedby "$($_.manager)"
}
```

Comment: Awesome! that worked. I did have another question  on the same topic. Using the script below;                              $office=get-aduser "samaccountname" -properties * | select office

I already tried $folder= get-aduser "samaccountname" -properties * | select '$(office)' and @{n='office';e={$_.office -replace '^office='$1'}} neither of which remove the @{office=} 

How do you remove the @{} from the output from a variable? subexpressions do not seem to work in this case

Comment: See Answer at [Your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149559/how-to-format-output-of-expanded-variable/17189271#17189271)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes:

```
set-distributiongroup -identity $_.dlgroup -managedby $_.manager
```

When you put it in quotes, PowerShell expands variables embedded inside double quoted strings,  and what you see (e.g @{...}) tells you that $_ is an object with two properties.